# VS Code Extension not uninstalling

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, publish, development-environment

I developed and published an extension for Visual Studio Code. Upon installing it (in Visual Studio Code), I was testing to see if it worked properly and it didn't, hence I uninstalled it, unpublished it, and fixed it. I performed this cycle 1 more time, and now I'm not being able to uninstall the extension from Visual Studio Code on my computer.

I tried using the terminal to disable it and then uninstall it, but its not working. On the other hand, I have unpublished it from the market and am able to publish it again. The interface where I'm facing the issue is within the "extensions" downloading and searching panel within Visual Studio Code.

Steps I took:

1. Uninstall extension from VS Code Extensions (this is where its not working):
   [Uninstalling image from VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yKGN.png)
   Over here, no matter how many times I click uninstall, the extension will not be uninstalled from my workspace.
2. Unpublish extension from Marketplace:
   [VS Code Marketplace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv1Q2.png)

Now even though I click the uninstall button and have unpublished it from the marketplace, the extension is still present in my workspace and I can't get rid of it.

Comment: can you please describe / show the exact actions you are taking to perform the things you said you did?

Comment: you don't need to publish to test the extension, use a launch config

Comment: @rioV8 I used the launch config to test the extension - I published it when I was finished and just wanted to see that it worked well, but there a discrepancy that appeared when I published it that weirdly was not there while I was testing

Comment: @starball, I'll add the exact steps to my post

Comment: `still present in my workspace` : an extension is not present in the workspace, it is part of VSC that has a workspace open, the workspace can be set to enable or disable an extension, have you looked at the extensions folder of VSC, is it still there, is it part of the `deleted` extensions (a json file with names)

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for the info, and no its not in the extensions folder and its not in the extensions.json folder either.

Comment: if you look at the logs, is the extension activated at startup of VSC, are the commands of the extension in the Command Palette

Comment: Yup they are, and I saw that is issue has "updated" since I last dealt with it. It shows me that it's installed under the Extension's panel, and when I click the uninstall button it says that the extension has uninstalled. However, when I open VS code again, the extension appears as an installed Extension that can be uninstalled once again @rioV8

Comment: how can VSC find the extension code and activate the extension when the code is not in the extensions folder. If this is the case create an issue asking for the location of the activated extension

Comment: I'm not sure how thats possible either, and sounds good I'll do that.